# SharePoint Online: How to remove vertical scroll bar in Embed webpart when using iframe?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, sitepages, iframe, embedded

I want to embed an image map into a modern SharePoint page. The code for the image map is saved as an .aspx file.

When I put `https://company.sharepoint.com/toolsresources/TestModernSite/SiteAssets/SitePages/Play/ImageMapTest.aspx` into the Embed web part, the image displays and the image map works but there is a vertical scrollbar.

When I put the URL into an iframe: `<iframe scr="URL" width="800" height="657"></iframe>`,

I get the error message:

> "We can't show this embedded content because the code seems to be incomplete. Make sure that the embed code includes width, height and a valid address for the src attribute."

I have also tried `<iframe scr="URL" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I found that without a Script Editor web part, I could post the image map if I reduced the size; that the Embed web part will accommodate an image that is 1000px wide x 575px high without the vertical scroll part.